# Sliding animation in Windows 8 in C# for Button content

Tags: animation, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, slide

I would like to create the following type of animation in Windows 8.1. I have a button whose content is an Image. I would like to change the image of the button and when I do so, I would like the old image to slowly slide out of view from the button to the right while the new image slides in from the left until it totally replaces the older image.
 I would like to have the C# code (not XAML) that would perform such a task. The reason I need this in code, is because the button is dynamically created (in fact I have multiple buttons created dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to subclass the `Button` control with one that has a template with two content presenters so you could alternate between these when the content changes and run the animations. Otherwise you can do it with code behind by having both `Images` hosted in a `Panel` (e.g. a `Grid`) in the `Button` and every time you want to change the image - set the `Source` of the unused `Image` and run the animation. You need to also alternate the animation targets unless you succeed to flickerlessly set the `Source` of a helper `Image` to the old bitmap and set the `Source` of the persistent `Image` to the new bitmap. That might  work as well. You would use `TranslateTransform` for the `RenderTransform` of each `Image` control and create `Storyboards` that target the transforms. Additionally you'd want to set the `Clip` of the parent `Panel` to a `RectangleGeometry` that clips the animating `Images` to the bounds of the `Panel` or the `Button` itself.